# How to make transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime, Camera.main.transform); move the object faster?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using `transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime, Camera.main.transform);` to make the object move in a direction based on the camera rotation. Is it possible to make this faster?

I haven't tried much I am just stumped

```cs
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime, Camera.main.transform);
    }
```

No error messages are showing up.

Comment: I assume this is Unity. If not, please feel free to rollback my edit and use the relevant tag(s).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "faster"? Is the update laggy? Are you asking for optimization suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the forward vector by your desired speed:

```
float speed = 10f;

Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime
```